# Python similarity on sets of strings via Pandas crashes memory. How can I make it work?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory, similarity

I'm struggling to get my python code to run, as I always run out of memory. So, I have the following data frame:
I have a column with a key and a column with features. This is a set containing a maximum of 10 strings that all have no spaces. And in this example I have about 70k rows.

```
              key                                                              features
    0    String A  {'Thisisastring', 'Thisisanothersentence', ... 'Maximumof10Strings'}
    1    String B                  {'Hellothere', 'Woop', ... 'Maxiningoutat10Strings'}
    2    String C        {'Yessir', 'Stackovervlowisawesome', ... 'Maximumof10Strings'} 
...
70000   String XY                     {'Aintnostring', 'Maybeitis', ... 'pleasehelpme'}     
...
```

Now what I want to do is to compare each of the feature-sets with all the other feature-sets and get their similarity. The similarity score is fairly easy in its code, as I only want, if there are 5 of the 10 the same, to give me 0.5 score of similarity, etc.:

```
def similarity_score(a, b):
    c = a.intersection(b)
    return 2 * float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b))
```

This is the current code, at the end I want to have a matrix, so that I can easily cluster them together based upon a similarity score threshold:

```
base_pd = original_pd['features']
i = base_pd.apply(frozenset, 1).to_frame()
j = i.assign(foo=1)
k = j.merge(j, on='foo').drop('foo', 1)
k.columns = ['A', 'B']
fnc = np.vectorize(similarity_score)
y = fnc(k['A'], k['B']).reshape(len(base_pd), len(base_pd))
queries = original_pd['key'].to_list()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=y, index=keys, columns=keys)
```

The issue is, though, that this wipes out my memory and uses > 25 GB quite early on. Obviously, it's also due to the huge amount of data with 70K rows, but there will be even possibilities of using even more rows, so I need to find a solution.

I've already tried with NumPy, to get around it a bit, but I'm not getting anywhere.

How could I make this more efficient? I need to use strings originally, obviously could change them to hashes or so, but even then I am a bit lost.

Best and thanks in advance,
Lukas

Comment: For each of 70k rows, you want to calculate and preserve a score against all other 70k rows. That will be a "table" of 4.9 billion entries right? Or is what you want to do is for each row find the n most similar rows?

Comment: No, that's correct, it would be 4.9 billion entries, yes.

Comment: Sure thing. just wanted to clarify as if you wanted only the best n matches it might be a significant savings.